# When i try to make a notification with winrt, no notification shows up

Tags: python, windows, notifications, windows-runtime

I am trying to make winRT send notifications. I tried doing this to make a notification:

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom

#create notifier
nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier("app-id");


tString = """
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Sample toast</text>
            <text>Sample content</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
"""

#convert notification to an XmlDocument
xDoc = dom.XmlDocument()
xDoc.load_xml(tString)

#display notification
notifier.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xDoc))
```

**Hoever, When i run it, no notification shows up.**

My system meets the requirements of winrt

```
Windows 10, October 2018 Update or later.
Python for Windows, version 3.7 or later
pip, version 19 or later
```

How do I make the notification show up? I can not use other modules, because winrt is the olny one (that I know of) where you can create ui elements on the notification such as buttons. I dont think windows is preventing it from showing because other modules that do not meet my requirements show notifications.

Comment: Read the *Remarks* section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager) to learn about requirements for Desktop applications.

Comment: @IInspectable So i made a shortcut for my python program on the startup screen. Now it says "The shortcut must have an AppUserModelID." How do i make it have an appid? Do i need to convert my python file to an exe?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Python's runtime to answer that question. Though you can try to assign an `AppUserModelID` to your process at run time. This [blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813) has sample code. It's C++ so you'll have to translate it to Python.